# Java final variable in function

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, final

```
void function_ab(){

if ( a == true){
    final Class_A obj = new Class_A("a"); //This is an example scenario, so I couldn't create a setter to pass in "a" instead of passing it into Contructor.
}else{
    final Class_A obj = new Class_A("B");
}

// the code below will access obj object in Inner class.

}
```

I need to access obj after the declaration, but since they are declared in 'if' block, I will not be able to access it after that. I can't do such thing like this also:

```
void function_ab(){

final Class_A obj = null;
if ( a == true){
    obj = new Class_A("a"); //final variable cannot be changed.
}else{
     obj = new Class_A("B");
}

// the code below will access obj object in Inner class.

}
```

The code above is not valid. So is the only way to get it works is to declare the obj variable as class variable? I try to avoid declaring like that because it only be used in that function only.

Please tell me if there is better way in solving this.

Comment: Help!!!!!!! I made a mistake again, I can't compile it in this case. Please look at the code example in my answer.

Comment: Where show us your error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
final Class_A obj = null;
```

You should be able to use

```
final Class_A obj;
```

This will allow you to initialize `obj` within an if statement- for more information, check out this description of [blank finals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Blank_final) from Wikipedia, a source that we may all trust with our lives.

Comment: Thank for help. I have made a stupid mistake, eclipse auto initialize it (assign null) for me when it detects an error and I never realize that I can remove the null.

Comment: Also note that, once you have added a value to a final variable you cannot reassign it again to another value.

Comment: Help, I made a mistake again, I can't compile it in this case. Please look at the code in my answer.

Comment: @KyelJmD In this case, what should I do? Please look at the code in my answer.

Comment: First, why are you making a final variable?

Comment: @KyelJmD, if we began to ask that, this entire question would fall apart XD

Comment: @KyelJmD Because I need to use that variable in the Inner class that is in that function.

Comment: @usernametbd Don't worry, a green tick belong to you. xD

Comment: I'll post all the details in my answer.

Comment: @KyelJmD I did post it, although I comment it out.

Comment: @GMsoF check out the answer I posted btw this isn't my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
final Class_A obj = a ? new Class_A("a") : new Class_A("B");
```

However, I don't know if there's a way to do this with more complex conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the answer of tbd and Xymostech + another info from me you can do the following.

1) On your code you declared the final variable like this `final Class_A obj = null;`

once you have assigned a final variable to a certain value you can no longer replace or reassign the value of it. For more information about that, please refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

That being said you are not allowed to do this

```
if ( a == true){
    final Class_A obj = new Class_A("a"); 
}else{
    final Class_A obj = new Class_A("B");
}
```

2) if you are going to use some other value or a simple computation to detemine let's say a boolean you can do this

```
final Class_A obj = a ? new Class_A("a") : new Class_A("B");
```

Judging from your code, you can do both of that given choices I have given you.

But from your code you can do this.

```
void function_ab(){

final Class_A obj;
if ( a == true){
    obj = new Class_A("a"); //final variable cannot be changed.
}else{
     obj = new Class_A("B");
}

// the code below will access obj object in Inner class.

}
```

Just remove the null assignment of  `final Class_A obj;`